# MvvmCross List - Click on item and button in item

Tags: listview, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I try to have a list that do different action with a button in the line item, and tap on the item list.

Here is the list

```
<Mvx.MvxListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/RecapResponsesListView"
    local:MvxBind="ItemsSource ReponsesRecapList; ItemClick GoToLandscapeQuestion;"
    local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/item_response" />
```

Here is the item response :

```
[...]
<Button
    android:id="@+id/ResponseValidate"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="20"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Valider"
    local:MvxBind="Click ConfirmResponseCommand; Enabled ConfirmButtonEnabled" />
</LinearLayout>
```

My button works fine, I can tap on it without any problem, but since I added it, the ItemClick no longer works. I can remove my button from the item, and the ItemClick works again, so it's not the implementation of this tap that doesn't. I think adding a button block the item click...

Do you have any ideas on why, and how to fix this ??

Thanks !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not really a MvvmCross issue, but an issue with focus and how descendants receive touch events on Android.

You should be able to fix your issue by adding

```xml
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

to the container with your button. Alternatively, if the button is not an `ImageButton` it may be sufficient to simply add

```xml
android:focusable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

to your button declaration.

Comment: thank you ! I used the second solution, and it worked !